# checking DB if records exists for a period of only 13 months

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a set of records in db and I need to check if records exists for more than a period of 13 months from the current date using the attributes date , month and year which are also saved in db as integer values.
I need to concatenate the integer values together and compare with current date to check if it exceeds a period of 13 months.

I am using postgres DB. tried different methods but not successful

Comment: i recommend posting some of your attempts

Comment: SELECT 
  *
FROM    agg_d_cause_f_cdr_datamart_fac
WHERE  
 Cast('(||date_dimension_year ||'+'-'+'||date_dimension_month||'+'-'+'||date_dimension_day||)'.to_date()) >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '13 months' 
  AND Cast('(||date_dimension_year ||'+'-'+'||date_dimension_month||'+'-'+'||date_dimension_day||)'.to_date()) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: this what i am trying and i still get error

Comment: select date_part('year',age(timestamp '2010-04-23')); -> returns 3
select date_part('month',age(timestamp '2010-04-23')); -> returns 11

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select count(*) 
from TABLE  
 where  now() - cast(date_dimension_year||'-'||date_dimension_month||'-'||date_dimension_day AS date) > INTERVAL '2 month';
```

Hi thanks all I did find out a solution but now I have to write a stored procedure or function such that if a record exists for the specified time period it should print either the total number of records or print only those records to a file.

I did run a small function but i dont know how to input the records only if it exists to another file?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalRecords ()
RETURNS integer AS $total$
declare
    total integer;
BEGIN       
      select count  (*)  into total  from agg_d_cause_f_cdr_datamart_fac  where now() - cast(date_dimension_year||'-'||date_dimension_month||'-'||date_dimension_day AS date) < INTERVAL '3 months';
   RETURN total;
END;
$total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: So glad you found an answer. Probably best to ask another question rather than tack on to this one.